# Accessing every 1st element of Pandas DataFrame column containing lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column containing lists objects

```
      A
0   [1,2]
1   [3,4]
2   [8,9] 
3   [2,6]
```

How can I access the first element of each list and save it into a new column of the DataFrame? To get a result like this:

```
      A     new_col
0   [1,2]      1
1   [3,4]      3
2   [8,9]      8
3   [2,6]      2
```

I know this could be done via iterating over each row, but is there any "pythonic" way?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use `map` and a `lambda` function

```
df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df.A.map(lambda x: x[0])
```

---

Comment: This looks like one of the most general/useful ways of manipulating series. Thank you.

Comment: This doe not work for me but df['A'].str.get(0) does

Answer (score 88):

As always, remember that storing non-scalar objects in frames is generally disfavoured, and should really only be used as a temporary intermediate step.

That said, you can use the `.str` accessor even though it's not a column of strings:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [[1,2],[3,4],[8,9],[2,6]]})
>>> df["new_col"] = df["A"].str[0]
>>> df
        A  new_col
0  [1, 2]        1
1  [3, 4]        3
2  [8, 9]        8
3  [2, 6]        2
>>> df["new_col"]
0    1
1    3
2    8
3    2
Name: new_col, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 18):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with `x[0]`:

```
df['new_col'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: x[0])
print df
        A  new_col
0  [1, 2]        1
1  [3, 4]        3
2  [8, 9]        8
3  [2, 6]        2
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the method [`str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) (same as [`str[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#indexing-with-str)):

```
df['A'].str.get(0)
```

It behaves similarly to the Python dictionary's `get` method, returning `NaN` if the desired index is missing. For example:

```
s = pd.Series([[1, 2], []])
s.str.get(0) # s.str[0]
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why does this work but df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df.A.map(lambda x: x[0]) does not? I keep getting this error meeage "IndexError: list index out of range"

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a conditional list comprehension which takes the first value of any iterable or else uses None for that item. List comprehensions are very Pythonic.

```
df['new_col'] = [val[0] if hasattr(val, '__iter__') else None for val in df["A"]]

>>> df
        A  new_col
0  [1, 2]        1
1  [3, 4]        3
2  [8, 9]        8
3  [2, 6]        2
```

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000)

%timeit df['new_col'] = [val[0] if hasattr(val, '__iter__') else None for val in df["A"]]
100 loops, best of 3: 13.2 ms per loop

%timeit df["new_col"] = df["A"].str[0]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop

%timeit df['new_col'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: x[0])
100 loops, best of 3: 12.1 ms per loop

%timeit df.A.map(lambda x: x[0])
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
```

Removing the safety check ensuring an interable.

```
%timeit df['new_col'] = [val[0] for val in df["A"]]
100 loops, best of 3: 7.38 ms per loop
```

Comment: Just be aware that `hasattr(..., '__iter__')` isn't a magic list identifier, it'll also work for strings, e.g. `hasattr('hello', '__iter__')` returns `True`, which may not be what you want.