# What is the pandas version of tidyr::separate?

Tags: python, pandas

The R package `tidyr` has a nice [separate](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) function to *"Separate one column into multiple columns."*

What is the pandas version?

For example here is a dataset:

```
import pandas
from six import StringIO
df = """  i  | j | A
         AR  | 5 | Paris,Green
         For | 3 | Moscow,Yellow
         For | 4 | New York,Black"""
df = StringIO(df.replace(' ',''))
df = pandas.read_csv(df, sep="|", header=0)
```

I'd like to separate the `A` column into 2 columns containing the content of the 2 columns.

This question is related: [Accessing every 1st element of Pandas DataFrame column containing lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125174/accessing-every-1st-element-of-pandas-dataframe-column-containing-lists)

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of `tidyr::separate` is [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with a special assignment:

```
df['Town'], df['Color'] = df['A'].str.split(',', 1).str
print(df)

#      i  j              A     Town   Color
# 0   AR  5    Paris,Green    Paris   Green
# 1  For  3  Moscow,Yellow   Moscow  Yellow
# 2  For  4  NewYork,Black  NewYork   Black
```

The equivalent of `tidyr::unite` is a simple concatenation of the character vectors:

```
df["B"] = df["i"] + df["A"]
df
#      i  j              A                 B
# 0   AR  5    Paris,Green     ARParis,Green
# 1  For  3  Moscow,Yellow  ForMoscow,Yellow
# 2  For  4  NewYork,Black  ForNewYork,Black
```