# Counting a list of words in a list of strings using python

Tags: python, pandas, count

So I have a pandas dataframe with rows of tokenized strings in a column named story. I also have a list of words in a list called selected_words. I am trying to count the instances of any of the selected_words in each of the rows in the column story.

The code I used before that had worked is

`CCwordsCount=df4.story.str.count('|'.join(selected_words))`

This is now giving me NaN values for every row.

Below is the first few rows of the column story in df4. The dataframe contains a little over 400 rows of NYTimes Articles.

```
0      [it, was, a, curious, choice, for, the, good, ...
1      [when, he, was, a, yale, law, school, student,...
2      [video, bitcoin, has, real, world, investors, ...
3      [bitcoin, s, wild, ride, may, not, have, been,...
4      [amid, the, incense, cheap, art, and, herbal, ...
5      [san, francisco, eight, years, ago, ernie, all...
```

This is the list of selected_words

```
selected_words = ['accept', 'believe', 'trust', 'accepted', 'accepts', 'trusts', 'believes', \
                  'acceptance', 'trusted', 'trusting', 'accepting', 'believes', 'believing', 'believed',\
                 'normal', 'normalize', ' normalized', 'routine', 'belief', 'faith', 'confidence', 'adoption', \
                  'adopt', 'adopted', 'embrace', 'approve', 'approval', 'approved', 'approves']
```

[Link to my df4 .csv file](https://pitt.box.com/s/s37b5ztq47mkebqyjwf40m4tyllewwg8)

Comment: Is each story entry a list containing a string as in `["it, was, a, curious, choice, for, the, good, ..."]`?

Comment: Yes I believe that each entry is a list of words. I used .split to separate the sentences into words. The counts need to be associated with each entry because I am correlating the counts with other data from the same dates as the stories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each story entry appears to be a list containing a string.

Use map to get the [string from the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125174/accessing-every-1st-element-of-pandas-dataframe-column-containing-lists) before applying str as follows.

```
CCwordsCount = df4.story.map(lambda x: ''.join(x[1:-1])).str.count('|'.join(selected_words))

print(CCwordsCount.head(20))   # Show first 20 story results
```

**Output**

```
0      1
1      2
2      5
3      7
4      0
5      1
6     10
7      8
8      2
9      2
10     8
11     0
12     0
13     2
14     0
15     4
16     2
17     9
18     0
19     0
Name: story, dtype: int64
```

**Explanation**

Each story was in a list converted to a string, so basically:

```
"['it', 'was', 'a', 'curious', 'choice', 'for', 'the', 'good', 'wife', ...]"
```

Converted to list of words by dropping '[' and ']' and concatenating words

```
map(lambda x: ''.join(x[1:-1]))
```

This results in words separated by commas in quotes.  For first row this results in the string:

```
'it', 'was', 'a', 'curious', 'choice', 'for', ...
```

Comment: @Jesse-BurtonNicholson Check one of your stories.  Does it have any of the selected words?

Comment: Yes, there are over 400 stories and most of them contain at least one of the selected_words

Comment: @Jesse-BurtonNicholson--the abbreviated version of the stories you provided did not have the selected words.  Can you give me more of the stories to test with?  Also, when I add some words from the stories in your post to the selected words then I get non-zero counts.

Comment: I have updated the post with a link to the exported .csv file for df4

Comment: BTW, Thanks so much for your help with this. My code worked at the end of last year and I just came back to it to update the project and it didn't work, it's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` function can be useful. And this can be implemented in many different ways. If you don't have any other purpose for the raw article and it can be a bunch of string. Then try this, you can also put them in a dictionary and loop over.

```
def find_words(text, words):
    return [word for word in words if word in text]

sentences = "0  [it, was, a, curious, choice, for, the, good, 1      [when, he, was, a, yale, law, school, student, 2      [video, bitcoin, has, real, world, investors, 3      [bitcoin, s, wild, ride, may, not, have, been, 4      [amid, the, incense, cheap, art, and, herbal, 5      [san, francisco, eight, years, ago, ernie, all"

search_keywords=['accept', 'believe', 'trust', 'accepted', 'accepts', 'trusts', 'believes', \
                  'acceptance', 'trusted', 'trusting', 'accepting', 'believes', 'believing', 'believed',\
                 'normal', 'normalize', ' normalized', 'routine', 'belief', 'faith', 'confidence', 'adoption', \
                  'adopt', 'adopted', 'embrace', 'approve', 'approval', 'approved', 'approves', 'good']

found = find_words(sentences, search_keywords)

print(found)
```

Note : I didn't have panda data frame in mind whine I create this.