# Get first list element in apply function Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a function `preprocess_names` that splits an input variable:

```
def preprocess_names(name):
    #SOME PREPROCESSING
    return name.split('')
```

Also, I have a Pandas DataFrame `df` to which I want to apply this function.
In my case, the `preprocess_names`'s output has length 3 and I want to use each value in a new column in `df`.

So, for the first new column, I want to use the first element from the output list. If I used this function on one str only, I would use `preprocess_names[0]` to get the correct variable. How can I do something similar while applying the method to df?

The code below raises `ValueError`, but is closest to what I would like to do.

```
df['runs'] = df['name'].apply(preprocess_names)[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want:

```
df['runs'] = df['name'].apply(preprocess_names).str[0]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125174/accessing-every-1st-element-of-pandas-dataframe-column-containing-lists/37125260

Comment: Can you convert to wiki?

Comment: @jezrael Ouch!!! Sorry, converted