# how to extract data inside a bracket in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column which has paranthesis with it. I would like to have only string inside it.

```
df:
ID  col1
1   [2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM]
2   [2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM]
3   [2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM]
```

Expected:

```
ID  col1
1   2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM
2   2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM
3   2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM
```

I tried with str.findall(r"(?<=[)([^]]+)(?=])") and also some other regex it is not working.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Just for clarity, in the original DF is `df['col1'][0]` the string literal `'[2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM]'` or is it a single-element list containing a string/timestamp `['2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM']`?

Comment: single-element list containing a string/timestamp

Comment: Then just extract the first element from the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing every 1st element of Pandas DataFrame column containing lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125174/accessing-every-1st-element-of-pandas-dataframe-column-containing-lists)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) with [`pandas.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) :

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].astype(str).str.strip("['']")
```

Output :
​

```
print(df)
   ID                    col1
0   1  2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM
1   2  2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM
2   3  2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

if its "single-element list containing a string/timestamp"

this is how to extract the first element as "MatBailie" said in the comments

```py
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Source**

Let's suppose we have the following dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3],
                   'Year': [['2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM'], ['2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM'], ['2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM']]
                   }).set_index('ID')
```

Source Visualization :

```
                        Year
ID                          
1   [2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM]
2   [2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM]
3   [2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM]
```

**Proposed command line**

```py
df1 = df1.explode(column='Year')
```

**Result**

```
                      Year
ID                        
1   2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM
2   2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM
3   2023/01/06:12:00:00 AM
```